# Python `argparse`: Is there a clean way to add a flag that sets multiple flags (e.g. `--all`" is equivalent to `--x --y`)

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I've got some Python `argparse` command-line processing code that initially looked like this:

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("--x", help = "Set `x`.", action = "store_true", default = False)
ap.add_argument("--y", help = "Set `y`.", action = "store_true", default = False)

ap.add_argument(
  "--all", help = "Equivalent to `--x --y`.",
  action = "store_true", default = False
)

args = ap.parse_args()

if args.all:
  args.x = True
  args.y = True

print "args.x", args.x
print "args.y", args.y
```

The basic idea: I have some boolean flags that toggle on a particular setting (`--x`, `--y`, etc), and I want to add a convenience option that toggles multiple settings on - e.g. `--all` is equivalent to `--x --y`.

I wanted to avoid having any command-line processing logic that was not contained within the `ArgumentParser` and done in `parse_args`, so I came up with this solution using custom `argparse.Action`s:

```
import argparse

def store_const_multiple(const, *destinations):
  """Returns an `argparse.Action` class that sets multiple argument
  destinations (`destinations`) to `const`."""
  class store_const_multiple_action(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(store_const_multiple_action, self).__init__(
        metavar = None, nargs = 0, const = const, *args, **kwargs
      )

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string = None):
      for destination in destinations:
        setattr(namespace, destination, const)

  return store_const_multiple_action

def store_true_multiple(*destinations):
  """Returns an `argparse.Action` class that sets multiple argument
  destinations (`destinations`) to `True`."""
  return store_const_multiple(True, *destinations)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("--x", help = "Set `x`.", action = "store_true", default = False)
ap.add_argument("--y", help = "Set `y`.", action = "store_true", default = False)

ap.add_argument(
  "--all", help = "Equivalent to `--x --y`.",
  action = store_true_multiple("x", "y")
)

args = ap.parse_args()

print "args.x", args.x
print "args.y", args.y
```

Is there any clean way of achieving what I want with `argparse` without either (0) doing some processing after `parse_args()` (first example) or (2) writing a custom `argparse.Action` (second example)?

Comment: What's wrong with post-parsing logic?  You don't have to make `argparse` stand on its head or dance a jig.  It's primary purpose is to parse the user's input.  But if custom Action classes make your code cleaner, then use them.

Comment: `add_argument('--all', dest='x',...)` could be used to set the value of `args.x`. That is, several Actions can set the same `dest`.  But there isn't a built in way of setting several `dest`.  A custom Action like your's is required.

Answer (score 1):

This is late, and not exactly what you wanted, but here is something you could try:

```py
import argparse

myflags = ['x', 'y', 'z']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--flags', nargs="+", choices=myflags)
parser.add_argument('--all-flags', action='store_const', const=myflags, dest='flags')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Then calling `python myscript.py --flags x y` outputs this

`Namespace(flags=['x', 'y'])`

And calling `python myscript.py --all-flags` outputs this

`Namespace(flags=['x', 'y', 'z'])`

But you'll have to check your flags via `'x' in args.flags` instead of simply `args.x`