# argparse store to multiple destination

Tags: python, argparse

I am writing a Python script. I have two variables with some default values. I want to pass one argument and set them to special values.

Can I do it directly using `argparse`?

My current code:

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-s', help="set special values", action='store_true')
args = ap.parse_args()
if args.s:
    # special
    args.a = 100
    args.b = 100
else:
    # default
    args.a = 10
    args.b = 10
print(vars(args))
```

I want to do something like this:

```
ap.add_argument("-s", 
                action="store_const",
                dest=["a", "b"],
                const=[100,100],
                default=[10,10],
                help="set special values")
```

Comment: Can you give a couple specific examples as to what options on the command line would give you what values?

Comment: I have added an example of what kind of function call I want do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`store_true` is a subclass of `store_const`.  That could be used instead:

```
In [309]: ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [310]: ap.add_argument('-s',action='store_const',default=(10,10),
     const=(100, 100));
```

Then `args.s` would be set to one tuple or the other:

```
In [317]: ap.parse_args([])
Out[317]: Namespace(s=(10, 10))
In [318]: ap.parse_args(['-s'])
Out[318]: Namespace(s=(100, 100))
```

You could also use `unpacking` to assign those values to `a` and `b` attributes

```
In [319]: args = ap.parse_args(['-s'])
In [320]: args.a, args.b = args.s
In [321]: args
Out[321]: Namespace(a=100, b=100, s=(100, 100))
```

You could also set `a` and `b` with a custom `Action` class, as shown in this question:

[Python `argparse`: Is there a clean way to add a flag that sets multiple flags (e.g. `--all`" is equivalent to `--x --y`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834678/python-argparse-is-there-a-clean-way-to-add-a-flag-that-sets-multiple-flags)

Comment: Appreciate your answer. You understood what I want. But this is not exactly what I want. I have added an example to illustrate that.

Comment: You'll have to write a custom Action class as illustrated in the linked question.

Comment: I see. That helps. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[From the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action), it says that `action='store_true'` will set your variable to `True`. Not another value. :)

Well, this is a way to do this...

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-s', type=int, default=None, help="set special values")
args = ap.parse_args()
if args.s:
    # special
    args.a = args.s
    args.b = args.s * 10
else:
    # default
    args.a = 10
    args.b = 10
print(vars(args))
```

As the code is pretty much simple and it is pretty much the same as yours, if you have questions, ask. :)

This code will either output...

a = 10 and b = 10, or a =, and b =<10 times this value>.

Usage : `python <your_file.py> -s=<your_number>`